# HTACCESS URL Rewrite not working making static url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have  problem i am using htaccess for add index.php and convert url also.

index.php working perfect but url is not converting.

Given url : http://example.com/allmodels/Samsung-mobiles_80

I want to convert into http://example.com/allmodels?st=Samsung-mobiles_80

I have used following syntax.

1:

```
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule .* index.php/$1
        RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ allmodels?st=$1 [NC,L]
```

2:

```
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ allmodels?st=$1 [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

3:

```
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ allmodels?st=$1 [NC]
        RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

I have try many syntax but all that not working for me.

I got error 404 page not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got my solution i used following code that is working for me.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ /allmodels?st=$1 [P,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [L]
```

And thanks fishy.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the suggested solution again according to the new information I got:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/allmodels/(.*)$ /allmodels?st=$1 [P,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [L]
```

RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 has to go second or otherwise the /allmodels-call will be rewrited to index.php/allmodels/(.*). Or you have to add the third line to exclude /allmodels-calls like I did.

R=301 and R=permanent is the same. Use whatever you prefer.

And finally make sure that the target file really exists ;)

---

**UPDATE**

Setting up your rewrite.log requires you to add following line right after "RewriteEngine on"

```
RewriteLogLevel Debug
```

After you did that, restart the apache and call your URL. Then have a look into /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log and you will see how your request is processed by the rewrite-module. Either post the result or describe it in such a way it will enable others to further support you. Thanks :)

**UPDATE-2**

After some back and forth it got clear that the suggested rule itself isn't the problem. But the way to ask for the final solution wasn't optimal^^

So I changed my solution by now to fit the approved correct and working version, with a 'P' for proxy instead of 'R' for rewrite to hide the orignal-URL that the user gets written to.

Comment: Which rule first write RewriteRule ^/allmodels/(.*)$ /allmodels?st=$1 [R=permanent,NC,L]    OR     RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]

Comment: Thanks. But your code is not working and target file is exist. I found  http://example.com/home/xyz/public_html/index.php/  url after used your code.

Comment: What exactly did you call to get to  example.com/home/xyz/public_html/index.php?? I can't think of any case that went through my suggested rules and end up there^^  What is your DocumentRoot? And are there other ProxyPass, Handlers or Rewrites to interfere with suggested rules? Can you make sure that these rules are even tested? --> add RewriteLogLevel 5  to your config --> reload/restart the apache

Comment: See      Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1                     this code is working but i want to add more rewrite rule that is not working

Comment: So your RewriteCond for checking if file or directory exists whould only be applied to RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 ??  Then again: .* catches ALL possible URIs including /allmodels and thus this is rewritten too.  So your 2nd option (of your original post) should be it, IF you add [R=301,NC,L] and a "/" to start the URIs -->  RewriteRule ^/allmodels/(.*)$ /allmodels?st=$1 [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried all the code but i don't know why this code is not working.

Comment: Can you give me some additional information on what your rewrite.log looks like when you set it to debug? --> add RewriteLogLevel 5 to your config --> reload/restart the apache

Comment: it is my original url  -----> http://mobifeature.com/allmodels?st=Samsung-mobiles_80    and i want to convert into --------> http://mobifeature.com/allmodels/Samsung-mobiles_80      i want to static url that works same as REQUEST.

Comment: I am pretty sure you didn't set your rewrite.log within 4 minutes and tested it. And I got your original question. But at this point I can't really help without a logfile-excerpt or at least an answer wether or not the suggested RewriteRule is even tested. I'll updat my answer to help you setting up the rewrite.log...

Comment: I have no access of apache . domain is hosted by godaddy.

Comment: Try this:  https://de.godaddy.com/help/viewing-traffic-apache-logs-in-the-hosting-control-panel-6653

Comment: Hello i have shared hosting plan so i have no access of apache logs. Can you tell me another solution.

Comment: The problem is that I already gave you a solution and you said it's not working. Now I need to know if these rewrite-block is applied at all. and either way a rewrite.log would help to understand how it is processed :( Currently I can't think of another solution that doesn't involve having a look in the rewrite.log...

Comment: I got following error in apache error log ===>    "GET /allmodels/Samsung-mobiles_80 HTTP/1.1" 404 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"

Comment: If you can see the error.log you should also be able to see the rewrite.log if you added the 'RewriteLogLevel 5' line in your config...should be more helpful, cuz i saw that i got the 404. But I want to see entrances like "applying pattern ... => not-matched" etc...

Comment: When I am using this code ==>  RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ /allmodels?st=$1 [R,L] it is working perfect but its redirect to original URL.

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understood that correctly: When you use the given code ==> RewriteRule ^allmodels/(.*)$ /allmodels?st=$1 [R,L] it works. That's good. But what do you mean by 'but its redirect to original URL', which 'original URL'? Didn't you want it to be rewritten to the orignal URL 'mobifeature.com/allmodels?st=Samsung-mobiles_80' ?? If you just meant that the shown-URL should stay the same, swap the R for a P --> [P,L]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working when i am using P that is working. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure :) Have fun with it ;)

Comment: I updated my answer to fit your need, with [P,L] for proxy and a short explanation. I would be delighted if you'd now mark the answer as 'correct' (green checkmark). Thanks in advance and good luck with future projects :)

Comment: Another problem is accure when i used P My Anchor tag is not working. Href url show http://mobifeature.com/allmodels/newpage but it should be like http://mobifeature.com/newpage

Comment: First I'd like to suggest that you update your original question. That will help others to understand what this is all about....Secondly: Your href is set by ??? In the given rules above there is none that does 'delete' /allmodels from a request... Gimme some context. May be updating your question ;)

Comment: Ehm, I understand that you wanted to mark the correct code as such...'correct'....but I edited mine before so it fits your solution^^ Would be great to be rewarded after all :)

Comment: I am not use ?? in href you can see ==> http://mobifeature.com/allmodels/Samsung-mobiles_80  click any menu and you can see the problem.